# Configure Features wizard not showing up

Tags: tfs

So I made some changes to a proccess template, some field updates, added a new WIT, and I went into ProcessTemplate.xml and I changed version number for Major to 2. I then uploaded it to TFS replacing the existing one. When I go to a project overview, the configuration wizard still wont show. Does anyone have any idea? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you expecting the configuration wizard to show up? Changes to process templates have to be applied individually to each team project via `witadmin`.

Comment: im reading that I should be able to based on this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/update-customized-process-template?view=tfs-2018

Comment: The wizard showing up when you upgrade your TFS version, not when you update the process template.

Comment: thats too bad, they really need to impement something for updating proccess templates, its pretty brutal having to go through 80 projects manually with so many changes. I did automate parts of it at least.